# Show instant notification if number input does not fulfill condition

Tags: r, shiny

I have a `textInput` in which the user should enter a number, for which I check if it is greater than 0 (the reason why I am using `textInput` instead of `numInput` is that I do not like the arrows coming with the latter). The number is used for further calculations. My goal is to show the user an instant notification if the input number is less than or equal to 0. By "instant" I mean once the user clicks outside the input field. I tried the following, but no notification is shown whatever the input:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(textInput("num_ipt", "enter positive number"))

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  pos_num <- reactive({
    validate(need(as.numeric(input$num_ipt) > 0), "Enter positive number")
      as.numeric(input$num_ipt)})}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

**EDIT:**

@Imran Ali, did you mean this?

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(textInput("num_ipt", "enter positive number"),
                verbatimTextOutput("numb"))

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  pos_num <- reactive({
    validate(need(as.numeric(input$num_ipt) > 0), "Enter positive number")
    as.numeric(input$num_ipt)})
  output$numb <- renderText(pos_num())

  }

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

This does not work. Instead of the number an error is shown in the output panel: "Error: argument 'label' is missing, with no default". Besides that, the number should not be outputted at all. In my real app it is only needed as an input for calculations.

**2. EDIT:**
@Stephane, your first snippet goes in the right direction, but it is not quite what I need as it only works if I output `pos_num`. If I remove the `output$numb`, it does not work:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(textInput("num_ipt", "enter positive number"))

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  pos_num <- reactive({
    validate(need(as.numeric(input$num_ipt) > 0, "Enter positive number"))
    as.numeric(input$num_ipt)})}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Try adding a `verbatimTextOutput("numb")` in your UI, then in your server code after the `reactive` add ` output$numb <- renderText(pos_num())`

Comment: If you don't mind adding additional dependencies, [`shinyBS::createAlert`](https://ebailey78.github.io/shinyBS/docs/Alerts.html) is a handy way to show such notifications. The example at the end of the page should be enough to get you started.

Comment: Also the package `shinyFeedback` is nice to show such messages.

Comment: @Joe I've seen your second edit where you mention me. If that does not work when you remove `output$numb`, that's probably because the reactive conductor `pos_num` has no descendant, then it is never executed.

Answer (score 1):

That does not work because the message must be an argument of `need`, while it is an argument of `validate` in your code.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(textInput("num_ipt", "enter positive number"),
                verbatimTextOutput("numb"))

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  pos_num <- reactive({
    validate(need(as.numeric(input$num_ipt) > 0, "Enter positive number"))
    as.numeric(input$num_ipt)
  })

  output$numb <- renderText(pos_num())

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

FYI, below is a way to print such a message with `shinyFeedback`:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyFeedback)

ui <- fluidPage(
  useShinyFeedback(),
  textInput("num_ipt", "enter positive number", value="1"),
  verbatimTextOutput("numb")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  observeEvent(input$num_ipt, {
    feedbackWarning(
      inputId = "num_ipt",
      condition = is.na(as.numeric(input$num_ipt)) || !(as.numeric(input$num_ipt) > 0),
      text = "Enter a positive number !"
    )
  })

  pos_num <- reactive({
    validate(need(as.numeric(input$num_ipt) > 0, message=FALSE))
    as.numeric(input$num_ipt)
  })

  output$numb <- renderText(pos_num())

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Where to find "shinyFeedback"? I tried CRAN and `devtools::install_github("shinyFeedback")`, both without success.

Comment: @Joe It is on CRAN: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/shinyFeedback/index.html